# Stars & Bars with limitations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've heard about the term Stars & Bars and found that it relates to a problem I'm attempting to solve, yet I'm not sure how to implement it.

The problem states that 3 fair dice are rolled, where every die has the numbers $[1,7]$, and we're tasked with finding the probability that the sum would be $14$.

My attempt in converting this to a stars & bars problem was the intuition that $|\Omega|=7^3$ , and we can notate $E$ for all solutions where the sum is $14$, hence $|E|$ would be the number of solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3=14$, with the restriction $1\leq x_i\leq7$.

If the restriction were $x_i\geq0$, this would be a simple plug into formula situation.

I've read on how to handle a one way limitation, for example $1\leq x_i$, though I'm unsure on how to approach a two way limitation (I assume it would require to split the problem and then reunite in some way).

Comment: If you let $y_i = x_i - 1$, then each $y_i$ is a nonnegative integer satisfying $y_i \leq 6$.  Moreover, $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 11$.

Comment: Wouldent the combination (for example) $(7,2,2)$ be counted there too?

Comment: That is true.  You need subtract those cases in which some $y_i > 6$.  Note there can be at most one such $y_i$ since $2 \cdot 7 = 14 > 11$.  Let me know if you need further help.  Please edit your question to show any attempt you make and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I was able to solve the problem according the method you've described.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that the number of solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 14, \,\,\;\; x_1,x_2,x_3\ge1$$

is the same as with

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 11, \,\,\;\; x_1,x_2,x_3\ge0$$

which is $\binom{11+3-1}{3-1}=78$.

Each solution that involves an $x$ larger than $6$ is therefore also a solution to

$$7+x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 11, \,\,\;\; x_1,x_2,x_3\ge0$$

or

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 4, \,\,\;\; x_1,x_2,x_3\ge0$$

which is $\binom{4+3-1}{3-1}=15$.

There are three ways that this $x$ can be placed, so the final answer is $78-3\cdot15=33$.

Comment: This is really interesting, does the number of solutions for $7+x_1+x_2+x_3=11$ cover all situations? (where there is $x_i = 7$ / $8$ / $9$ / $10$ and $11$)

Could you possibly elaborate more about the intuition behind that?

Comment: @Aishgadol It does cover all solutions since we are allowing $x_1, x_2, x_3$ to vary over the nonnegative integers.  You could also find the number of solutions to the equations $7 + x_2 + x_3 = 11$, $8 + x_2 + x_3 = 11$, $9 + x_2 + x_3 = 11$, $10 + x_2 + x_3 = 11$, and $11 + x_2 + x_3 = 11$.  Notice, that they have, respectively, $5, 4, 3, 2, 1$ solutions and that $5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15$.  Since we can permute the roles of the variables, there are $3 \cdot 15 = 45$ prohibited cases.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that by now you have solved your problem using stars and bars, here's an algebraic approach you may like.

Basically, we need to find

coefficient of $x^{14}$ in the expansion of $(x+x^2+x^3+...+x^7)^3$
= coefficient of $x^{11}$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+....+x^6)^3$
$= [(1-x^7)/(1-x)]^3$
$= (1-x^7)^3\cdot(1-x)^{-3}$

Expand the second term using the negative binomial Theorem, and collect coefficients of $x^{11}$, thus

$[1-\binom31 x^7]\cdot[1+\binom31 x + \binom42 x^2 + ...+\binom64 x^4 + ...+\binom{13}{11} x^{11}]$

$= 1\cdot\binom{13}{11} - \binom31\cdot\binom64 = 33$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig was able to supply a more intuitive approach to this.

I cant wrap my head around your solution, I've never seen this way of approaching a 'stars & bars' problem using coefficients.

Is there a wikipedia/online page where I can read more about this approach?

Comment: @Aishgadol  true blue anil is using [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) to solve the problem.

Comment: @Aishgasol: Yes, I have used generating functions, but for solving die toss problems, you don't need to have an in-depth understanding of generating functions. If you can follow what has been done algebraically, it is an alternative way that can be used.